# Composite template being sent multiple times

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

When sending out the composite email each Recipient is getting two status records generated and need to sign all documents twice.

I've tried changing the sequence to be incremented, and also moving the composite template to different places in the json constructed. Nothing seems to effect the number of times the signers are required to respond.

Here's the JSON output

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Documents",
    "emailBlurb": "Email subject, sign these documents",
    "templateId": "template 1 Id",
    "SourceId": "an opportunity Id",
    "envelopeIdStamping": "false",
    "templateRoles": [ 
        {
        "roleName": "Signer 1",
        "name": "First Signername",
        "email": "First Signer email",
        "recipientId": "first signers Id"
        },{
        "roleName": "Signer 2",
        "name": "Second Signername",
        "email": "Second Signer email",
        "recipientId": "second signers Id"
        }],
    "status": "sent",
    "notification":
        {
        "UseAccountDefaults": "true"
        },
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
            "sequence": "1",
            "templateId": "template 1 Id"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {"sequence": "1",
            "customFields":
                {
                "textCustomFields":[
                    {
                    "value":"an opportunity Id",
                    "name":"Opportunity",
                    "configurationType":"salesforce"
                    },{
                    "value": "an opportunity Id",
                    "show": "false",
                    "required": "true",
                    "name": "DSFSSourceObjectId",
                    "fieldId": null
                    }]
                },
                "recipients":
                    {"signers":[
                        {"roleName": "Signer 1",
                        "name": "Second Signername",
                        "email": " Second Signer email",
                        "recipientId": "second signers Id"
                        },{
                        "roleName": "Signer 2",
                        "name": "First Signername",
                        "email": " First Signer email",
                        "recipientId": "first signers Id"
                        }]
                    }
            }]
        },{
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
            "sequence": "1",
            "templateId": "template 2 Id"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
            "sequence": "1",
            "customFields":
                {
                "textCustomFields":[
                    {
                    "value":"an opportunity Id",
                    "name":"Opportunity",
                    "configurationType":"salesforce"
                    },{
                    "value": "an opportunity Id",
                    "show": "false",
                    "required": "true",
                    "name": "DSFSSourceObjectId",
                    "fieldId": null
                    }
                ]
                },
                "recipients":
                    {
                    "signers":[
                        {
                        "roleName": "Signer 1",
                        "name": "Second Signername",
                        "email": " Second Signer email",
                        "recipientId": "second signers Id"
                        },
                        {
                        "roleName": "Signer 2",
                        "name": "First Signername",
                        "email": " First Signer email",
                        "recipientId": "first signers Id"
                        }]
                    }
            }]
        },{
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
            "sequence": "1",
            "templateId": "template 3 Id"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
            "sequence": "1",
            "customFields":
                {
                "textCustomFields":[
                    {
                    "value":"an opportunity Id",
                    "name":"Opportunity",
                    "configurationType":"salesforce"
                    },{
                    "value": "an opportunity Id",
                    "show": "false",
                    "required": "true",
                    "name": "DSFSSourceObjectId",
                    "fieldId": null
                    }
                ]
                },
                "recipients":
                    {
                    "signers":[
                        {
                        "roleName": "Signer 1",
                        "name": "Second Signername",
                        "email": " Second Signer email",
                        "recipientId": "second signers Id"
                        }]
                    }
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TemplateRoles parameter in the root Envelope Definition should not be used with CompositeTemplates - You'll need to remove that.

Once that's gone, you'll want to check your ServerTemplates to confirm your signer roles are in alignment. In order for roles to merge correctly, both the RoleName and the RoutingOrder must match in all templates.

Comment: Thanks Drew, 

That solved my issue. I also had to remove the TemplateId that was listed outside the composite template section. Without removing that it errors on 'invalid email address' since TemplateRoles is gone apparently.